# Can't get rid of horizontal rule in ionic popup

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am struggling to remove a horizontal rule in my ionic popup. The very faint horizontal rule can be seen here:

[image]

The CSS I am using to style the popup is as follows (the border stuff makes no difference at all):

```html
.popup {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 12px 18px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.72);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 12px 18px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.72);
  box-shadow: 10px 12px 18px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.72);
  background-color: white !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  border-bottom: none !important;
  border-top: none !important;
}
.popup-head .popup-title{
  background-color: #336688;
  color: white;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  border-bottom: none !important;
  border-top: none !important;
}
.popup-sub-title {
  margin-top:20px;
  font-size:15px;
  border-bottom: none !important;
  border-top: none !important;
}
.popup-body {
  border-bottom: none !important;
  border-top: none !important;
  margin-top:0px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

A demonstration of the horizontal rule can be seen at the ionic codepen example for ionic popup at [ionic popup example](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/zkmhJ)

Comment: Create a demo of the output here: http://play.ionic.io

Comment: You really need to post a code demo that demonstrates the problem. Otherwise, it's not safe to assume you know where the problem is coming from.

Comment: Ok it turns out the codepen demo for ionic popup shows the same horizontal rule. This can be seen at: http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/zkmhJ

Comment: Hm, not for me What browser are you viewing this in?

Comment: I am using Firefox on a Mac. I get the same line (it is VERY thin) on Safari and when running on the iPhone simulator